# Can not reuse OpenCV::VideoWriter

Tags: c++, opencv, video, avi

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and OpenCV 2.4.5.

I have a class that contains processed video frames and I'd like to save them as video files. I created a cv::VideoWriter object in constructor and write frames to cv::VideoWriter object by looping and get the wanted video successfully. The problem starts after getting the first video.

I also sometimes want to end this video file by cv::VideoWriter::release() and reuse this object by reopening it with a different name like below:

```
outputVideo.release();

outputVideo.open("D:\\example2.avi", CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X'), 15, videoSize, true);
```

but I realised that for the second time, the VideoWriter doesn't create any file at the related path even the cv::VideoWriter::isOpened() function returns true interestingly.

But the more interesting thing, I also can not create and use any other instance of cv::VideoWriter object in anywhere else of my class. The more and more interesting thing is, I can create and use several instances in Constructor only.

Tried many things; pointers, different codecs, creating objects in constructor and using them in other methods, with no help.

The only thing I see that I  can only create one instance and use it for only one time, I can not use it again after releasing it or I can not create a new instance and open it if I'm out of the constructor of my class, even isOpened() method always returned true (no file is being created on related path except the first time). Found nothing to help me about this weird problem on the internet.

Any help is really appreciated, spent my 3 hours and couldn't understand why.

Comment: did you compile in release mode and link debug libraries or vice-versa? Can you create a minimum compilable example (e.g. a main function) that still gives you problems?

Comment: @Micka thanks for reply. I've figured out it was due to lack of opencv_ffmpeg dll but the strange thing is that it works for only one time without the desired dll, I don't know how.

Comment: @Horizon1710 how did you solve the problem? Can you please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70130274/record-multiple-videos-from-webcam-stream-in-opencv-c?noredirect=1#comment123970366_70130274

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that this problem is caused due to the lack of *opencv_ffmpeg.dll* file. But still weird to me that it works for only one time without the desired dll. I don't understand how it achieves to work without this dll file.